# Is a power distribution board just a board that connects all grounds and all positives?

Tags: power-supply, power, pcb

I'm thinking of designing a PCB for a quadcopter but want to directly integrate the power distribution board (power going to the ESCs that power the rotors). I would just like to confirm that it's as simple as connecting all the grounds together and then connecting all the positive connectors (as per [this link](https://www.dronetrest.com/t/power-distribution-boards-how-to-choose-the-right-one/1259))? Or is there more to it?

In addition, I do need some kind of voltage regulator so that the battery can also power the Arduino running the quadcopter - can I simply use an LM7805 voltage regulator given my battery is 12V?

Comment: It is whatever you make it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the power distribution board you linked is, electrically, just connecting the different power and ground supplies together respectively. It appears they also use it as a mechanical frame for a quadcopter.

You can use the LM7805 for your Arduino. The current draw is presumably low, so the linear regulator won't be burning much power. Just note that the linear regulator is less efficient the more current you draw from its output. If your +5V supply will be powering much other than the Arduino, you should look into using a switch mode power supply (buck), as that will be more efficient at higher current draw.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Just did some research and I did not know that buck converters were that much more efficient